# Limiting size of google drive folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I have google drive of 1TB storage but my local computer hard drive is 150 GB. How can I limit the size of my google drive folder on my machine e.g. google drive folder dont exceed 50 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. What you can do instead is configure it to only sync certain folders to your computer. Maybe you have one huge folder you dont want to sync for example.